# When using drag and drop tracking areas not detected/defined

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstrackingarea

My problem is that when I'm dragging something in my view, my tracking areas are not detected.

I have a text and I've defined some tracking areas so that if I go over a specific part of the text I change his background. Now my problem is that tracking areas are not detected when i go over them while dragging something.

Is there any why to aloud tracking areas detection while using the drag and drop?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC you need to pass the `NSTrackingEnabledDuringMouseDrag` option to `initWithRect:options:owner:userInfo:`.

Comment: Actually I already added this option and more exactly I have: `NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited|NStrackingMouseMoved|NSTrackingEnabledDuringMouseDrag|NSTrackingActiveAlways`. Is there anything wrong?